# There is some inconsistent/confusing workflow managing contacts from smart groups?

Tags: groups, smartgroups

CiviCRM allows add and remove contacts from smart groups. This is an useful functionality that allows us to cover some cases managing groups.

However this functionality often leads to confusion among users that found a group with a mixed contacts that have been added and removed manually and others that meet the search criteria of the smart group. It might be useful if the system somehow warned when you are adding or removing contacts on a smart group?

Despite this, since the time you can add or remove a contact to a group there should have the possibility to manage this membership from the contact summary group tab in the same way that can be made with regular groups. I seem to recall that this possibility had existed in the past, but maybe I'm wrong.

I'm right or I'm missing something?

Because of this non covered functionality I've gone crazy more than once looking why a contact appeared on a group if in their sumary contact group tab there is no information about if it has been added manually or by a smart search criteria.

[image]

Comment: not sure if it is easy to implement but would it help if the group 'vol asesoria juridica' - which is i assume a Smart Group - were to show eg with an asterisk if it is listed in 'Group regulars' which might help you realise that the person has been manually 'added' to a Smart Group?

Comment: Isn't the case, 'vol asesoria jurídica' is a regular group. The problem is the other way. For example, contact was added manually at 'Voluntarios - activos' group that is a smart group and moreover contact no matches the smart group criteria. But sure, it would help if this smart group added status be marked in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19435 fixes the static assignments to smart groups.

Comment: Yes, it is that! I had been looking from top to bottom in the issues list and I had not seen. Thanks Thomas.